# Error parse json to arrayList

Tags: java, json, parsing, arraylist, gson

My json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "anneeMois": "201611",
    "dateModification": "2016-04-18",
    "montantValide": "500.00",
    "nbJustificatifs": "3",
    "visitorId": "1",
    "etat": {
      "id": "1",
      "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "anneeMois": "201617",
    "dateModification": "2016-08-16",
    "montantValide": "650.00",
    "nbJustificatifs": "7",
    "visitorId": "1",
    "etat": {
      "id": "1",
      "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
    }
  },
```

my class

```
public class FicheFrais implements  java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String anneeMois;
    private Date dateModification;
    private float montantValide;
    private int nbJustificatifs;
    private int visitorId;

    @SerializedName("etat")
    private Etat etat;
```

my class Etat

```
public class Etat  implements  java.io.Serializable{

   private  int id_etat;
   private String lib_etat;
```

I would like parse my json to `List<Frais>`

I have used

```
List<FicheFrais> mesFichesFrais =   unGson.fromJson(sb.toString(),TypeToken.get(new ArrayList<FicheFrais>().getClass()).getType());
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please define ["doesn't work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Do you get error/exception/incorrect results?

Comment: Try this: List<FicheFrais> mesFichesFrais = new Gson().fromJson(sb.toString(), new ArrayList<FicheFrais>().getClass()).getType());

Answer (score 0):

Your json seem to be wrong, it starts with [ and ends with },
if you want it to be a list it should start and end with []

```
    [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "anneeMois": "201611",
    "dateModification": "2016-04-18",
    "montantValide": "500.00",
    "nbJustificatifs": "3",
    "visitorId": "1",
    "etat": {
      "id": "1",
      "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "anneeMois": "201617",
    "dateModification": "2016-08-16",
    "montantValide": "650.00",
    "nbJustificatifs": "7",
    "visitorId": "1",
    "etat": {
      "id": "1",
      "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
    }
  }
  ]
```

but I recomend you to create an object containing the list, something like

```
        {
  "myList": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "anneeMois": "201611",
      "dateModification": "2016-04-18",
      "montantValide": "500.00",
      "nbJustificatifs": "3",
      "visitorId": "1",
      "etat": {
        "id": "1",
        "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "anneeMois": "201617",
      "dateModification": "2016-08-16",
      "montantValide": "650.00",
      "nbJustificatifs": "7",
      "visitorId": "1",
      "etat": {
        "id": "1",
        "libEtat": "Saisie clôturée"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also recommend using http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to check if your json is correct